# mysql 5.6.3 issue with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default value on TIMESTAMP field

Tags: mysql

I've been through many of the questions that are similar to mine, but all seem to relate to trying to use a default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with a DATETIME field.

I am having a problem using a CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default with a TIMESTAMP field which I understand is supposed to be supported.

I am using MySQL 5.6.3 community edition.  Here is a partial extract of my table creation code:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `my_table` (
`master_id`    INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`template_id`   INT(10) NULL,
`def_id`    INT(10) NOT NULL,
'override`  TINYINT(1) NULL,
`last_update` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ...
```

This errors out:

Invalid default value for 'last_update'

Any ideas why?

Comment: Define the filed as `last_update TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and try again. I tested this on 5.7 so I've no idea  if it works on 5.6 (hence the comment).

Comment: For the record it is not the backticks - that's a copy/paste issue.  I've used the correct quotes in the actual statement.

Comment: Defining the field as above without the NOT NULL doesn't help.

Comment: I tested my suggested solution on 5.5 and 5.7 (no access to 5.6 at this point) and it gives correct result. I know it's not a back tick issue, I just didn't include them in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

Someone (not me) had set the following on the MySQL my.cnf:

explicit_default_for_timestamp = 1

Removing this setting resolved the issue.